# Setting Accessibility Label In a Custom Navigation Item View

Tags: ios, swift

I have a storyboard with a Navigation Item which nests a stack view with 2 labels. In the respective viewcontroller, I have set these labels in viewdidLoad() with Accessibility identifiers and labels, but when I run a simulator with accessibility inspector, neither of these labels are recognized. **Is there a way to set an Accessibility Label on 2 labels nested in a  Navigation Item?**